# Можно ли использовать write() вместо send(), и есть ли в этом смысл?

Tags: c, сокет, posix

Можно ли использовать `write()` вместо `send()`, и есть ли в этом смысл?

Читал си-код *http-сервера*, в одном моменте там используется `write()` вместо `send()`, вот фрагмент:

```
send(clients[n], hdr , sizeof(hdr) - 1, 0);
size_t f_sz = fd_size(fd);
printf("%lu\n",f_sz);
sprintf (data_to_send, "Content-length: %lu\r\n", f_sz);
write (clients[n], data_to_send, strlen(data_to_send));
send(clients[n], "\r\n", 2, 0);
    
while ((bytes_read=read(fd, data_to_send, BYTES)) > 0)
{
    write(clients[n], data_to_send, bytes_read);
}
```

Comment: Странная смесь для одного файла с кодом. Обычно `write()` пишут, когда не знают, с каким именно `fd` (сокет, терминал, pipe или обычный файл) работает функция (и вообще-то, это  более в духе \*nix, так что глубокий смысл в этом есть)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Единственная разница между `send()` и `write()` наличие флагов. С нулевым параметром флагов, `send()` эквивалентно `write()`.

C `recv () / send ()` у вас есть дополнительный флаг `flags`, который позволяет вам выполнять
различные специальные действия, которые иногда могут понадобиться. 
А `read () / write ()` - это в основном то же самое, что и
`recv () / send ()` со значением flags 0 ... 
 Так что, если вам не нужно какое-либо
специальное поведение flags, это на самом деле просто вопрос вкуса, какой из
них вы хотите использовать .

Comment: Добавлю, что это так для всех «нормальных» posix-систем, но стоит помнить, что winsocks это не поддерживает...